# Open a file on server's dispaly device

Tags: server

Ubuntu 18.04 server is running on a laptop connected to a TV via HDMI. I able to see to CLI environment, but I don't have access to the keyboard. Now, there is a file on this server that I wish to open on the server, so it would be displayed on the TV. How can I achieve this with the help of an external Linux machine(laptop)?

Answer (score 0):

You want the `fbi` if I understand you correctly, it will display an image using the frame buffer for the console to display thus onto a `cli` screen displayed on the TV. You would connect to the laptop at the TV via a `ssh` connection to be able to control it remotely.